# Using ncurses - trying to understand wgetch()

Tags: ncurses

I created a single-window menu scheme using ncurses and got it working.
When I added a second window, I can no longer get my wgetch call to fire (or so it seems).

Somewhat confusing to me is the function prototype :

```
int wgetch(WINDOW *win);
```

which says wgetch somehow depends on the window but I don't get the relationship - how does "the window" matter? If it does, and I have more than one window, which one do I use?  Also,  https://linux.die.net/man/3/wgetch says "There is just one input queue for all windows." which tells me "the window" is a "don't care".

Can someone explain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window *matters* because **`wgetch`** **refreshes** the window before reading characters.  That's in the [**`wgetch`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) manual page:

> If the window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified since the
>   last call to **`wrefresh`**, **`wrefresh`** will be called before another character
>   is read.

Each window (including **`stdscr`**) may have been altered since the last call to **`wrefresh`**.  If you make changes in one window without refreshing it, and then call **`wgetch`** in another window, the changes to the first window are not automatically displayed.  You can use [**`wnoutrefresh`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html#h3-wnoutrefresh_doupdate) to combine refreshes, e.g., using that for the first window and then use the **`wrefresh`** done automatically for the second window to refresh both.